# Android Gson Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

First let me say, I have searched before posting, just cant find the answer.

I want To Get an api which is Like this

[
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7
]

and then add RecylerView  .

Model
Seats.java

////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

```
public class Seats {

    @SerializedName("seatNo")
    private int seatNo;




    public int getSeatNo() {
        return seatNo;
    }

    public void setSeatNo(int seatNo) {
        this.seatNo = seatNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return
                "seats{" +
                        "unique_id = '" + seatNo + '\'' +
                      
                        "}";
    }
}
```

SeatsAdapter

```
public class SeatsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeatsAdapter.SeatsViewHolder> {


    private SeatsActivity seatsActivity;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Seats> seatsList;
    //Context ctx;

    public SeatsAdapter(SeatsActivity seatsActivity, Context context, ArrayList<Seats> seatsList) {
        this.seatsList = seatsList;
        this.seatsActivity = seatsActivity;
        this.context = context;
        //this.ctx = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public SeatsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout
                .item_seat, parent, false);

        return new SeatsViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SeatsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Seats seats = seatsList.get(position);
        holder.mTvSeatNo.setText(seats.getSeatNo());
    
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return seatsList.size();
    }

        protected class SeatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ImageView mIvSeatSelected;
        private ImageView mIvSeat, mTvSeatLadies, mIvSeatBooked;
        private TextView mTvSeatNo;

        public SeatsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mIvSeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeat);
            mIvSeatSelected = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeatSelected);
            mTvSeatNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSeatNo);
            mTvSeatLadies = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeatLadies);
            mIvSeatBooked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeatBooked);


        }

    }
}
```

And Here is activity.java

```
  private void initParcelRcv() {
        seatsList = new ArrayList<Seats>();
        rcvSeat= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcvSeat);
        rcvSeat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        SeatsAdapter = new SeatsAdapter(this,this,seatsList);
        rcvSeat.setAdapter(SeatsAdapter);
    }

   private void getSeatsInfo() {


        Utils.showCustomProgressDialog(this, getResources().getString(R.string
                        .msg_waiting_for_get_documents),
                false, null);



        Call<List<Seats>> call =  ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class)
                .getSeats(busName,departure,arrival,departuretime);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Seats>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Seats>> call, Response<List<Seats>> response) {

                if (parseContent.isSuccessful(response)) {

                    List<Seats> seats = response.body();
                   seatsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(seats.toArray()));

                    SeatsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();
                }
                else {
                    Utils.showErrorToast(response.body().hashCode(),
                            SeatsActivity.this);
                    Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Seats>> call, Throwable t) {
                AppLog.handleThrowable(SeatsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), t);
                Utils.showToast(SeatsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), SeatsActivity.this
                );
                Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have to provide some more information, code examples etc. to show more precisely want you want to achieve.

Comment: I have Adeed all Infomation Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code expects "{", but found a number instead. You should check your JSON first (please, write a resulting JSON in your question, I think it is `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]`).

I see you use this POJO in `Seats.java`:

```
@SerializedName("seatNo")
private int seatNo;
```

This is a wrong model, because your JSON consists of a list of integers.

Maybe you should remove `Seats.java` and rewrite a callback:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Integer>>() {
```

UPDATE

Simply replace `Seats` with `Integer` (I didn't check).

```
Call<List<Integer>> call =  ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class)
                .getSeats(busName,departure,arrival,departuretime);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Integer>> call, Response<List<Integer>> response) {

                if (parseContent.isSuccessful(response)) {

                    List<Integer> seats = response.body();
                    seatsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(seats.toArray()));

                    SeatsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();
                }
                else {
                    Utils.showErrorToast(response.body().hashCode(),
                            SeatsActivity.this);
                    Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Integer>> call, Throwable t) {
                AppLog.handleThrowable(SeatsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), t);
                Utils.showToast(SeatsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), SeatsActivity.this
                );
                Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Could you Please share me Full code How I can handle it

Comment: - COOLMIND you are amazing it works perfect  could you Please Give me your email or your contact

Comment: @MohamedMohamudZardheye, thank you! Glad to hear it!